# add tapGestureRecognizer to UIImageView in UIView and call method by protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimageview

I want to make touch recognized on an UIImageView(orange) in an UIView(blue). And hopefully, handle the touch event in a delegate method, which will be used in other classes. However, I can't make touch recognized with below code. How can I implement to recognize touch only in the ImageView(orange).

[image]

code:

```
import UIKit

protocol CustomViewDelegate {
    func imageViewTapped()
}

class CustomView: UIView {

    var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?
    var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapped))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.addSubview(imageView)
    }

    public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func tapped() {
        print("tapped method called")
        delegate?.imageViewTapped()

    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, CustomViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
        view.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(view)
    }

    func imageViewTapped() {
        print("come to view controller")
    }

}
```

Comment: I figured out that it almost work
`self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)` instead of 
`imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)`. However, it recognize the touch of all blue part

Comment: enable the userInteraction for imageview from storyboard.

Answer (score 2):

UIImageView default userinteraction is false, so enable imageView userinteraction in CustomView init.

```
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Different UITapGestureRecognizer to different views and handle as per your requirement . or add tag and access like this

```
 func tapOneAct(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if let tag = sender.view?.tag {
        switch tag {
        case 1:
            println("First View Tapped")
        case 2:
            println("Second View Tapped")
        default:
            println("Nothing Tapped")
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

enable `isUserInteractionEnabled` property on UIImageView as it defaults to false

```
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomView.tapped(_:))) 
imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
self.addSubview(imageView)
```

in `tapGesture` method

```
func tapgesture(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
     if sender.state == .ended {
        let touchLocation: CGPoint = sender.location(in: sender.view?.superview)
        if imageView.frame.contains(touchLocation) {
            print("tapped method called")
            delegate?.imageViewTapped()
        }
    }
}
```